# How to find the solution of system of equations by using the method of manufacturing solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I want to use the method of manufacturing solution MMS to find the exact solution of the following linear system of two equations

$$\begin{cases} u_t -(u_{xx} + u_{yy}) =  u + v\\
v_t -(v_{xx} + v_{yy}) = -u + v
\end{cases}$$

I assumed $u$ and $v$ any functions such as $u = e^t \sin(\pi x) \sin(\pi y)$ and $v = e^t \cos(\pi x) \cos(\pi  y)$ and then plugged them in the system but unfortunately they did not satisfy the system. I do not how to use MMS in this case. Can anyone with experience about this help me in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is going to help, but you could try separating the time variable by solving
$$\begin{bmatrix}u_t\\v_t\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\-1&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}u\\v\end{bmatrix}$$
Then we can solve the characteristic equation
$$\det\begin{bmatrix}1-\lambda&1\\-1&1-\lambda\end{bmatrix}=\lambda^2-2\lambda+2=(\lambda-1)^2+1^2=0$$
With solutions $\lambda=1\pm i$. If $\lambda=1+i$, then
$$\begin{bmatrix}-i&1\\-1&-i\end{bmatrix}\xrightarrow{R_2+iR_1}\begin{bmatrix}-i&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix}$$
So an eigenvector is
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}$$
And a solution vector is
$$\begin{bmatrix}1\\i\end{bmatrix}e^te^{it}=\begin{bmatrix}e^t\cos t\\-e^t\sin t\end{bmatrix}+i\begin{bmatrix}e^t\sin t\\e^t\cos t\end{bmatrix}$$
Since both the real and imaginary parts are separately solution vectors, we can now try
$$\begin{align}u(x,y,t)&=e^t\cos(t)f(x,y)+e^t\sin(t)g(x,y)\\
v(x,y,t)&=-e^t\sin(t)f(x,y)+e^t\cos(t)g(x,y)\end{align}$$
Substituting all that into the original partial differential equation, we find
$$\begin{align}\cos(t)\nabla^2f+\sin(t)\nabla^2g&=0\\
-\sin(t)\nabla^2f+\cos(t)\nabla^2g&=0\end{align}$$
And finally we can eliminate $t$ to get $\nabla^2f=0$ and $\nabla^2g=0$, so any two harmonic functions $f(x,y)$ and $g(x,y)$ will lead to a solution.